# Understanding $\sigma$-algebras of random variables and tail events through a problem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am having some trouble understanding how to interpret $\sigma$-algebras related to a sequence $\{X_n : n \geq 1\}$ of random variables, especially tail events. I have found some great explanations online about why certain random variables (such as $\{\underset{{n \to \infty}}{\limsup}X_n \ \text{exists} \}$ are tail events, but I am having trouble expanding my understanding beyond these basic examples.

In particular, I found this great example which I am unable to answer completely, but I think if I can understand how it works, then I will be better able to understand these concepts more generally.

Suppose that $\{Y_0,Y_1,Y_2,\ldots\}$ are i.i.d. random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ with the following distribution:

$$ \mathbb{P}(Y_k = -1) = \mathbb{P}(Y_k = 1) = \frac{1}{2}, \ \ k \geq 0.$$

Furthermore, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \geq 1$, we define:

$$X_n := Y_0 Y_1 \cdots Y_n. $$

Now, suppose I have the following $\sigma$-algebras:

$$\mathcal{Y} := \sigma(\{Y_1, Y_2, Y_3 \ldots \}) \ \text{and} \ \mathcal{T_n} := \sigma(\{X_n, X_{n+1}, X_{n+2} \ldots \}), \ n \geq 1. $$

Furthermore, let:

$$\mathcal{L} := \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \sigma (\mathcal{Y} \cup \mathcal{T_n}) \ \text{and} \ \mathcal{R} := \sigma \bigg(\mathcal{Y} \cup \bigg ( \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \mathcal{T_n} \bigg) \bigg). $$

The goal is to show that $\mathcal{L} \neq \mathcal{R}$. One suggested approach is to show that $Y_0 \in m \mathcal{L}$ (i.e. $Y_0$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{L}$) and $Y_0$ is independent of $\mathcal{R}$.

One problem I am having is understanding why $\mathcal{Y} \neq \mathcal{T_n}$, as $Y_n$ and $X_n$ have the same probability distribution and $\{X_n : n \geq 1 \}$ are independent.

I truly appreciate any help with solving this problem (hints, solutions, references etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For why $\mathcal Y \ne \mathcal T_n$, you can think about the easiest case where $n = 1$.  Then $\mathcal T_1 = \sigma(X_1) = \sigma(Y_0Y_1)$, so knowing $Y_1$ and $\mathcal T_1$ tells you $Y_0$.  This is the reason $Y_0$ is $\mathcal L$ measurable - $Y_0$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(\mathcal Y \cup \mathcal T_n)$ for all $n$ because knowing $Y_i$ for $i \ge 1$ and any $X_n$ is enough to find $Y_0$.

Comment: Hi @user6247850, that explanation helps a lot. So, when it says that "$Y_0$ is independent of $\mathcal{R}$", does this mean that $Y_0 \notin m \mathcal{R}$?

Comment: It's a stronger statement than $Y_0 \not \in m\mathcal R$ - it means $P(\{Y_0 \in  B\} \cap A) = P(Y_0 \in B) P(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal R$ and Borel sets $B \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So, with respect to $\mathcal{R}$, is it fair to say that "If I know $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ and I know some tail event $T \in \cap_{n \geq 1} \mathcal{T_n}$, then it is impossible to determine the value of $Y_0$"? Or is it more intuitive to say "The value of $Y_0$ has no influence on any tail events"? I'm assuming these are saying the same thing, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I think the second one, and I would phrase it as "No tail events contain any information about the value of $Y_0$".  If you think of two independent $N(0,1)$ random variables $X_1, X_2$ and let $S := X_1 + X_2$, then even if you know $S$ it is impossible to determine $X_1$, so $X_1$ is not $\sigma(S)$ measurable.  However, $S$ still has some information about $X_1$ (if $S$ is large, it means $X_1$ was probably large), so $X_1$ is not independent of $\sigma(S)$.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. I'm still working through how to express these ideas in more formal notation so I can write some kind of proof, but your explanations really did help a lot. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help explain these concepts in detail.